# Converting Days to Weeks in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a total amount of X days into X amount of weeks in C++, this is what I've seen done online and is not working:

```
int weeks = ((days % 365) / 7);
```

For example, if days = 8, then technically it is onto week 2 so int weeks should be = 2. Similarly 15 days should output 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own code instead of finding it online?

Comment: Have you tried adding 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `days` is an integer type, you can use:

```
int weeks = (days + 6) / 7
```

This works because integer division truncates any fractional part.

Comment: `days` must be `int` or `long int` or other `int`s which cannot contain fractions and can only contain whole number.

Comment: @afriza, I would say it's a safe bet it's an integral type. I would seriously question the sanity of someone that used floating point to represent days :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: FYI, I am taking half-day leave on the 6th week of 2013. So if the HR system doesn't accept floating points, my leave balance won't be calculated properly. And they show me the remaining balance in `days`.

Comment: @afriza, I think you'll probably find that HR works on an hourly rate. They may present days to you but calculations will be done on a smaller resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division will truncate the result. In order to get the number of weeks, you'll need to take the `ceil` of the division. If you only want those days that represent weeks within a year, you keep the mod, else, don't.

In other words:

```
int weeks = (int)ceil(days / 7.0);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/

Answer (score 0):

You just add one if there are days left

```
int weeks = days / 7 + (days % 7 ? 1 : 0);
```